# multiline text set in defference time

Tags: android

I want to develop a speech to Text app by using Android. I delivered my speech, then it will be converted into text, but when I speech again, then the previous line destroy and a new line can be set. But I don't want this...
I want to set all of the lines....

This is my Code...

```
ArrayList<String> matches = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            if (matches != null)
            {
                editText.setText(matches.get(0)+". ");
            }
```

Comment: What you want is to use `.append()` instead of `.setText()`

Comment: Many many thanks,for  your suggestion